# Null Pointer exception within a try catch block

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Getting the following runtime error, causing my application to crash on launch

> E  FATAL EXCEPTION: MonitoringThread  13533         AndroidRuntime  E 
>   Process: foo.com, PID: 13533  13533         AndroidRuntime  E 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException  13533         AndroidRuntime  E   at
>   foo.com$MonitoringThread.run(foo.java:125)  13533
>   AndroidRuntime  E     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

The offending line is

```
ret = mConnection.getInputStream().read(buffer);
```

in the following code snippet

```
try {
    ret = mConnection.getInputStream().read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    break;
    }
```

Can anyone suggest next steps in trying to debug?
I thought that use of a try catch block would eliminate any null pointer errors.

Comment: Have you initialized `mConnection`?

Comment: no, a try catch block does not get rid of errors. I just gives you an opportunity to react on them

Comment: where is `mConnection` initialized?

Comment: @eco_bach you are catching only IOException !!

Comment: Also, when you catch an exception you should do something with it such as display a message, change a variable, etc... not just let it sit and stew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use try / catch blocks to eliminate null pointer exceptions. Null pointer exceptions should be passed down, to let programmer know that problem arises and where.

In your case, you are catching IOException, so its not NullPointerException.

Also check what is null that is causing this exception, maybe its mConnection ? or getInputStream() returns null.

From this example, you can also see that its best to not execute lots of methods in one line:

```
ret = mConnection.getInputStream().read(buffer);
```

its better to write:

```
InputStream is = mConnection.getInputStream();
ret = is.read(buffer);
```

this way you will know from callstack where NPE originated,

if your code is unsafe, like you know you can get nullpointer from some method, then simply check it:

```
InputStream is=null;
if ( mConnection != null ) {
   is = mConnection.getInputStream();
   if ( is != null ) {
     ret = is.read(buffer);
   }
   else {
      // log error?
   }
} 
else {
   // log error?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    ret = mConnection.getInputStream().read(buffer);
    } catch (Exception e) {

     Log.e("your app", e.toString());
     break;
    }
```

Should solve the issue

Comment: "Should solve the issue" - not really, because NullPointer will still be there... this is ignoring a problem, not solving it.

Comment: And do you know the purpose of Log.e()? That's there to tell what is the cause of Exception.

Comment: thanks, although the answer below by marcin_j is more detailed, this helps a great deal.

Comment: The **break;** is useless there @UmerFarooq

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possibilities. Either `mConnection` is `null`, `getInputStream()` returns `null`, or `buffer` is `null` and the `read()` method is throwing the NPE. My best guess would be `mConnection` is `null`, that's where I'd start.

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
    ret = mConnection.getInputStream().read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    break;
    }
```

> break  ret = mConnection.getInputStream().read(buffer); this statement

```
 try 
 {

   if(mConnection!=null)
   {
     InputStream reader=mConnection.getInputStream();
     if(reader!=null)ret= reader.read(buffer);
   }
 } catch (IOException e) 
 {
        break;
 }
```